# How do I break from notifier.watch

Tags: ruby, inotify

I'm using ruby 2.5.1 and [rb-inotify](https://github.com/guard/rb-inotify) I have the following

```
@notifier = INotify::Notifier.new
@notifier.watch("#{ENV['HOME']}/Downloads", :moved_to, :create) do |event|
  puts "#{event.name} is now in Downloads dir."
  break if event.name == "filename"
end
puts '1'
@notifier.run
puts '2'
```

I want to stop the notifier once it finds a certain filename and continue with the script. Is this possible?

When I break from the notifier.watch I get the following error;

```
LocalJumpError: break from proc-closure
```

Comment: Have you tried to use `@notifier.stop`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is [`@notifier.stop`](https://github.com/guard/rb-inotify/blob/50d6264f6a40cba35b4cc36e18afab85a820e79f/spec/notifier_spec.rb#L28)